# iAd Producer - How to open YT links in Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube, safari, iad

I have an error with the iAd browser that does not allow YouTube videos to play. Apple’s workaround is to implement a `javascript` call on all YouTube-link `button` taps that launch the link in the Safari web browser instead of the in-app browser using `window.location` in the `JS`.

Code implemented:
`window.location = "http://…"`;

But still not launching in the Safari web browser.

**Main Code:**

```
this.onViewActivate = function (event) {

window.location = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eM8Wpq-oD5o&index=3&list=PLbh4x6U6o9F6sLbGWaAtgdvEmceJLYgwO";

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You code should be using this process:

`document.location = 'http://...`

because the iAd producer is within a UIWebView. this will prompt to user and let them know they are about to quit the application.

Comment: We also tried that code but still not launching in the Safari web browser. I'm not sure but is this something to do with the length of YT link? My link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V06yrjyuT30&list=PLbh4x6U6o9F6sLbGWaAtgdvEmceJLYgwO&index=4

Comment: Here is the code: this.onViewActivate = function (event) {
    window.location = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eM8Wpq-oD5o&index=3&list=PLbh4x6U6o9F6sLbGWaAtgdvEmceJLYgwO";

Comment: please update the it on the question. it is barely visible in comments

Comment: I have updated my question with the code at the bottom.